# sftp file age: reading files transferred from sftp that aren't complete yet

Tags: linux, sftp

I have a linux server that receives data files via sftp.  These files contain data that is immediately imported into an application for use.  The directory which the files are sent to is constantly read by another process looking for the new files to process.

The problem I am having is that the files are getting read before they are completely transferred.  Is there a way to hide the files before they have transferred?

One thought I had is by leveraging the .filepart concept that many sftp clients use to rename files before they are complete.  I don't have control of the clients though, so is there a way to do this on the server side?

Or is there another way to do this by permissions or such?

Comment: Look at here http://serverfault.com/questions/282897/openssh-sftp-server-filepart-support

Comment: Kind of a different problem and I don't really follow how the solution works.  Is there no setting on the sftp server to handle this?

Comment: *NO* As far i know, There is no such option in sftp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have solved a similar problem by creating a directory on the same file-system that the files will be read from by the clients, and use inotifywait.

You sftp to the staging directory and have inotifywait watch that staging directory.

Once inotify sees the "FILE_CLOSE" event for any received file you simply "mv" the file to the directory the client reads from.

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -m -e close --format "%f\n" /path/to/tmp | while read newfile
do
  mv /path/to/tmp/"$newfile" ~/real
done
```

Comment: This looks like a good fit thanks.  Do you happen to have a sample script?

Comment: Something like this should do the trick; untested!   See edited post above.

Comment: Thanks.  So in this scenario how does inotifywait know to keep watching the directory forever?  Because basically we have to look for these files endlessly

Comment: That's what the -m flag does.